# Docker volume is empty

Tags: docker

When using `-v` switch the files from container should be copied to localhost volume right? But it seems like the directory `jenkins_home` isn't created at all.

If I create the `jenkins_home` directory manually and then mount it, the directory is still empty.

I want to preserve the jenkins configs so I could re-run image later.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `docker run -v jenkins_home:...` where the first half of the `-v` option has no slashes in it at all, that syntax creates a named Docker volume; it isn't a bind mount.

If you `docker run -v "$PWD/jenkins_home:..."` then that host directory is mounted over the corresponding container directory.  At startup time, nothing is ever copied into the host directory; if the host directory is empty, that empty directory gets mounted into the container, hiding everything that was in the image.

If you use the `docker run -v named-volume:...` syntax, and the named volume is empty, then in this case only, and only the very first time the container is run, the contents of the image are copied into the named volume.  This doesn't work for bind mounts, and it doesn't work if there is already data in the volume (perhaps from a previous `docker run`).  It also does not work in other container environments such as Kubernetes.  I do not recommend relying on this behavior.

Probably the easiest way to make this work is to launch a one-off container to export the contents of the image, and then use bind-mount syntax:

```sh
cd jenkins_home

docker run             \
  --rm                 \ # clean up this container when done
  -w /var/jenkins_home \ # set the current container directory
  jenkins/jenkins      \ # the image to run
  tar cf - .           \ # write a tar file to stdout
| tar xf -               # and unpack it on the host

# Now launch the container as normal
docker run -d -p ... -v "$PWD:/var/jenkins_home" jenkins/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Turned out that by default it creates the volume in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/` instead of in the current directory.

Also I had tried `docker volume create jenkins_home` before running the docker image to mount. So not sure if it was the `-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home` or if it was `docker create volume` that created the directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`.

Comment: If you haven't explicitly `docker volume create`d the volume, `docker run -v volume-name:...` will create it for you.  Either will create the directory inside Docker's private implementation-details-subject-to-change directory tree.